# Flowplayer: SWF file not found

Tags: javascript, flowplayer

I'm writing a live TV application using Flowplayer 6.0.5.
I'm using the following code:

```
 <div class="player">
    <video>
        <source type="application/x-mpegurl" src="http://10.10.11.101/response2/index.m3u8?ch=<?php echo $_SESSION['chnId']; ?>&request=playlist&session=<?php echo $sess_id; ?>">
    </video>
</div>
var playero = $('.player').flowplayer({
        autoplay: true
     });
```

It's working fine during livestream, but when I switch channels or use seek I occasionally (about once in 10 times absolutely randomly) get this error:

[image]

When switching channels (same when using seek), I just send the request to server to change the playlist and then use

```
player.load();
```

I have searched everywhere but couldn't find why could this be happening.
Any help will be appreaciated, thanks!

Comment: Using `//releases.flowplayer.org/6.0.5/flowplayer.swf` means it will use the same protocol (HTTP or HTTPS) as the serving page.  I checked the path of both `http://releases.flowplayer.org/6.0.5/flowplayer.swf` and `https://releases.flowplayer.org/6.0.5/flowplayer.swf` and tried refreshing them multiple times and it seems to be working ok.   Cant it be a problem with your internet connection?   One other question.. why not using player.setClip() instead of doing player.load() everytime?

Comment: That's why I have no idea why this could be happening randomly. Problem is not in connection as this problem occurs from any different place.

Comment: The error indicates that the SWF file is not found.  So, your best bet would be to monitor the browser's Console (under Network) and see what goes on in the network calls when this error occurs.  Have you tried serving the flowplayer.swf file in your own server?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that, in fact, I'm serving that file locally at this moment. It still happens randomly. Could it be a flowplayer bug?

Comment: Nothing unusual happens in network either:
http://imgur.com/8ysGeOr

Comment: what "unusual" do you expect in the network console just by looking? search for the flowplayer.swf in the list and open the link in new tab. see if the player exists. also could you host some live example somewhere so we can try playing around with it?

Comment: Do you really think flowplayer.swf wouldn't exist and I would post this question? Frankly, I'm not that stupid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Believe it or not, I suspect the issue is your app being mistaken for some Flash adverts provider.

Browsers don't think "Oh FlowPlayer? That one's okay", all they know is an SWF file embedded on the page is constantly loading various unique streams (like rotating a playlist of video adverts? Oh oh).

This now makes your app show same behaviour as those annoying Flash banners.
It is then auto-blocked (like all Flash banner ads are nowadays) until user chooses to enable playback.

I'm confused by seeking though. network activity did not show new requests but yet for you it gets blocked after a while? I tested this **[FlowPlayer link](http://flash.flowplayer.org/plugins/streaming/rtmp.html)**.

All I know is these things below will avoid auto block...

- If the SWF is loaded from same server as .html that embeds, thats fine.
- If the SWF is loading videos from same server as itself, thats fine.
- If the SWF is loading a single video source, that's fine.

You're likely doing the first thing but it's not possible to do the second one since video is from RTMP server.

For yourself : Can PHP be used here as a "middle man" proxy? Basically for RTMP streaming, point your SWF input URL to the PHP file (so technically its always loading one file) but the PHP should `Echo` back any changed RTMP stream data (channel or seeked).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion!
I was doing the 1st and 3rd things already, but I didn't think it would get auto-blocked for loading videos from different server. I followed your suggestion of using PHP as "middle man" and it seems to have solved the problem. Learned new thing today, thanks!

Comment: By the way, when I moved SWF file to my server, the error became less frequent, but still happened occasionally. So it seems like some random logic from browsers for me.

Answer (score 0):

Please update  your flowplayer version from your flowplayer [account page](https://flowplayer.org/account), because there are some fixes made in your version(6.0.5). You can review that [fixes](https://flowplayer.org/news/releases/html5/v6.0.5.html).